# Define maximum jobs in queue inside lsb.queues

Tags: lsf

I am trying to find out how many jobs a queue that I defined can hold.

Which parameter holds the maximum number of jobs that can be submitted to a specific queue?

Answer (score 0):

When you say max jobs in a queue, I assume that you mean pending, suspended and running, but not done or exit.  Here are the closest options that I can think of.

1. Use an esub to enforce the limit.  While this can get you what you want, its a little hairy.  You can use the NJOBS field of bqueues to get the current number of jobs in the queue.  This option has a small race condition as some time passes between the check and submission.
2. There's a global limit for pending jobs.  lsb.params, MAX_PEND_JOBS
3. The lsb.queues parameter QJOB_LIMIT can limit the max job slot for running jobs. But it limits job dispatch, not job submission.
4. Similar to 3 except you can limit jobs rather than job slots.  Do this with a limit in lsb.resources.